# What is the group for the following presentation?

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation

This group has four generators $a, b, c$ and $d$. Generators satisfy the following relations:

1. $a$ commutes with $b$ and $c$ commutes with $d$.
2. $a^2=b^2=1$ and $c^{m_1}=d^{m_2}=1$ for some integers $m_1,m_2\geq3$.
3. $(ac)^{n_1}=(ad)^{n_2}=(bc)^{n_3}=(bd)^{n_4}=1$. Here $n_i\geq3$.

Comment: Does $(ac)^{n1}$ here mean $(ac)^{n_1}$?

Comment: What do you want to know about the group? It is a Coxeter group, and infinite provided that the $n_i$ are all at least $3$.

Comment: @MJD Yes $n1$ is an integer. I am now writing $ni$ as $n_i$.

Comment: @DerekHolt .Thank you very much for your reply. I don't know mathematics much. Now I got a direction to study it. If possible, please give me some simple and good references.

Comment: You could start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxeter_group

Comment: @DerekHolt, I am modifying the second relation. Can you tell me the group now?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "tell me the group". You have to be more precise. What do you want to know about the group?